# Flask app using single html template with multiple callback functions

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am in the process of learning Flask app building and I am running into an issue that I am not sure what I am missing.

In my app, I am trying to use a single HTML template by passing params to either clone a record or create a new record. The difference is, when clone is clicked, it will pre populate the form with the values of existing record vs loading the empty form when new record is being created.

Below is my HTML template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>{% block title %} Add a New Job {% endblock %}</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <label for="job">Job</label>
        <br>
        <input type="hidden" name="id"
           placeholder=""
           value="{{ request.form['id'] or jobs['id'] }}">
        </input>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="hidden" name="act"
           placeholder=""
           value="{{ request.form['act'] }}">
        </input>
        <br>
        <br>
            <input type="text" name="jobname"
               placeholder="Job Name"
               value="{{ request.form['job_name'] or jobs['job_name'] }}">
            </input>
        <br>
        <label for="mi">Minute</label>
        <br>
            <input type="text" name="mi"
                placeholder="mi"
                value="{{ request.form['mi'] or jobs['mi'] }}">
            </input>
        <br>
        <label for="hr">Hour</label>
        <br>
            <input type="text" name="hr"
                placeholder="hr"
                value="{{ request.form['hr'] or jobs['hr'] }}">
            </input>
        <br>
        <label for="dom">Day of Month</label>
        <br>
            <input type="text" name="dom"
                placeholder="dom"
                value="{{ request.form['dom'] or jobs['dom'] }}">
            </input>
        <br>
        <label for="moy">Month of Year</label>
        <br>
            <input type="text" name="moy"
                placeholder="moy"
                value="{{ request.form['moy'] or jobs['moy'] }}">
            </input>
        <br>
        <label for="dow">Day of Week</label>
        <br>
            <input type="text" name="dow"
                placeholder="dow"
                value="{{ request.form['dow'] or jobs['dow'] }}">
            </input>
        <br>
        <label for="cmd">Command</label>
        <br>
            <input type="text" name="cmd"
                placeholder="cmd"
                value="{{ request.form['cmd'] or jobs['cmd'] }}">
            </input>
        <br>
        <label for="desc">Description</label>
        <br>
            <input type="text" name="desc"
                placeholder="desc"
                value="{{ request.form['desc'] or jobs['jdesc'] }}">
            </input>
        <br>
        <label for="status">Status</label>
        <br>
            <input type="text" name="status"
                placeholder="status"
                value="{{ request.form['status'] or jobs['status'] }}">
            </input>
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Below is the Python code that is calling this template.

```
@bp.route('/create_job/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def create_job(id, act):
    if act == "clone":
        job_list = Jobs.query.get_or_404(id)
    else:
        job_list = Jobs.query.get(0)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        job_name = request.form['job_name']
        mi = request.form['mi']
        hr = request.form['hr']
        dom = request.form['dom']
        moy = request.form['moy']
        dow = request.form['dow']
        cmd = request.form['cmd']
        desc = request.form['desc']
        status = request.form['status']
        new_job = Jobs(    job_name=job_name,
                           mi=mi,
                           hr=hr,
                           dom=dom,
                           moy=moy,
                           dow=dow,
                           cmd=cmd,
                           description=desc,
                           status=status
                        )
        print(new_job)
        db.session.add(new_job)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('job.index'))
    return render_template('job/create_job.html', jobs=job_list)
```

When the home page is loaded, I can see that the link for new record is passing default value of "0" for the id and "new" as the action and same is true for the "clone" link as it has the record id for the record that is being cloned and "clone" as action.

But the application is generating the error for missing positional argument

Below is the base.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %} {% endblock %} - MyApp</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <a href="{{ url_for('main.index') }}">Home</a>
        <a href="{{ url_for('job.index') }}">Jobs</a>
        <a href="{{ url_for('job.create_job', id=0, act='new') }}">New Job</a>
        
    </nav>
    <hr>
    <div class="content">

        {% block content %} {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the error message that is displayed on the terminal window running flask app

```
TypeError: create_job() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'id' and 'act'
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2023 20:50:42] "GET /job/create_job/?id=0&act=new HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Can anyone help in identifying the issue with this?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the definition of the model class.

Comment: You should decide whether you want to use [variable rules](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/#variable-rules) or URL parameters via [`request.args`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#flask.Request.args) for the `act` and `id` variables. A database query for jobs with id 0 is not necessary because the ids only start with 1.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers Detlef!! That helped resolve the issue. Appreciate your help.